# Remove in app purchase item from new app version

Tags: ios, iphone, in-app-purchase

I have a second 1.0.1 version of app in app store with some in app purchase items.
In new version I do not want to use one item and I want to delete it from IAP items.
Did anybody had some case like that?
I think just to not use IAP API to purchase or restore buying that item in new version and leave the item in itunes connect for the old version.
What do you think?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

go on itunes connect and delete it from the in-app purchases module in your app

Comment: I think I will do that so that "top in app purchase" part in app store does not have that item, because users might be confused it they saw it in list :)

Answer (score 0):

don't delete or remove from sale your purchase item in itunes connect. if you do; current users can't open/use that feature. 
if you want to remove in app purchase in your app, just design your app without using purchase item (make it free), then submit. 
so, current users can purchase that item without any problem until your app's new version release.

I suggest don't rush to delete your in app purchase item in iTunesconnect after new version released. Because some users may not update their app soon.